# Python automatically enter credentials

Tags: python, credentials

I'm trying to write a simple script in Python in order to start IBM Notes when Windows starts and automatically enter the credentials.

IBM Notes already starts with Windows and has the username set already but the password needs to be entered.

How do I make python 3.7 to enter the password in the window that pops up?

This is my code that works. I just need that last part.

```
from subprocess import call 
call(['C:\\Programas\\Notes\\notes.exe'])
```

Comment: Thx for the hate guys!! Its great! :))

Answer (score 1):

> How do I make python 3.7 to enter the password in the window that pops up?

It is not an easy task. You should try to see if you can run notes.exe with parameters (user and password).

```
call(['C:\\Programas\\Notes\\notes.exe --user <username> --password <password>'])
```

But i'm not sure that notes executable has that kind of parameters